# Trigger when user hits enter but not when focus is lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am trying to trigger an event when the user types a search string and hits enter.  I don't want to trigger it when the input loses focus (as this may happen when the user clicks other buttons for search options).  Both

```
$("#search-input input").val("").change(function () {
```

and

```
$("#search-input input").val("").on('change', function () {
```

trigger both when the user types something and hits enter, but also when the user clicks on something outside the search box.  What would be the correct trigger for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Indeed, that does the opposite of what I am trying to do (it triggers when I change focus, but not when I hit enter)

Comment: You're right. I misread the second part of the question as "trigger both when..."

Comment: Stick it in a form and a listen for a submit, works with most conceivable scenarios, even without javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#search-input input").val("").on("keypress", function(e){
  if(e.which==13){
    //handle it here.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  (It seems a little inelegant and inefficient to trigger on every keypress, but otherwise fine.)  I'm surprised there isn't a "named event" for hitting the enter button in an input.

Comment: like someone else mentioned, a more efficient solution would be to bind on the form's submit event if that would work in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

you can use keypress event and check if enter key is pressed. something like this:

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#search-input input", function(e) {
     if (e.which == 13) {
         //do some stuff
     }
});
```